# One mongoDB-instance, many DBs - how to connect a user to "their" DB without affecting other users?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm building an application (MVC) that will use 4 collections in a DB. When I add new clients to the application they will get their separate DB. So if I have 10 customers, there will be 10 DBs and 40 collections (1 db -> 4 collections)

This way each customer data is seperated from other customers, which is crucial here.

So far I've built the app and everything is working nicely, 'cept one thing.

If Company A logs in and start using the app everything works fine. But when Company A is logged in, and Company B logs in, both Company A AND B will be directed towards Company B:s DB.

I've looked trough my code and I guess this is my own fault because I use .connect (mongoose). When a company logs in the route will fire of a controller that will open a new connection (which overrides the old one) which will redirect all open connections towards that specific DB.

**controller.dBlogin.js**

```
mongoose.connect(dbConfig.url + id, options)
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Successfully connected to the database");
        next();
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('Could not connect to the database. Exiting now...');
        process.exit();
    });
```

The **id** is fetched from req.params.id (example: http://webapp.com/login/:id).

As far as I've figured .connect only allows one connection at a given time so I need something that will, simply, allow many connections. So I'm thinking that I could use .createConnection for this,

- https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#multiple_connections

But i just cant get it to work.

I changed **controller.dBlogin.js** to

```
mongoose.createConnection(dbConfig.url + id, options)
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Successfully connected to the database");
        next();
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('Could not connect to the database. Exiting now...');
        process.exit();
    });
```

but that only leads to a timeout when the company logs in. How do I use the .createConnections? How do you go from .connect to .createConnection?

**Heres the examples of routes, controller, and a model (user-schema).**

**routes.js**

```
// connect to db, check auth
app.post('/login/:id', dbController.connectDB, dbController.login)
```

**controller.dbLogin.js**

```
exports.**connectDB** = (req, res, next) => {

const id = req.params.id;

// Get Mongoose to use the global promise library
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

// Options Conncetion mongodb
const options = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
};

// Connecting to the database
mongoose.connect(dbConfig.url + id, options)
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Successfully connected to the database");
        next();
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('Could not connect to the database. Exiting now...');
        process.exit();
    });
};

exports.login = (req, res, next) => {

passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect: '/start', // redirect to the secure profile section
    failureRedirect: '/login', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
    failureFlash: true // allow flash messages
})(req, res, next);
```

};

Example of a model **user.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
const Company = require('../models/company.js');

// define the schema for our user model
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
local            : {
    name : {
        type: String, 
        required : true
    }, 

    email        : {
        type     : String,
        unique   : true,
        required : true
    },

    password     : String, 

    active       : Boolean,

    company      : {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Company'
    }
}
});

    // generating a hash for password
userSchema.methods.generateHash = function(password) {
return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
};

// checking if password is valid
userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.local.password);
};

// create the model for users and expose it to our app
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Comment: What is the standard practise when it comes to building an app that will be used by many different companies and you do not want to keep all the data in the same DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for the ones who finds themselves in the same spot:

After reviewing my app and the data it will keep I came to the conclusion that there is no need for splitting multi-tenancy. I reworked the app so when the user fetch or write data they only touch "their" data, and this is controlled backend.

But, I did make a post on mongoose github and got an answer,

See post here: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/7386

The author gave a great length which seems to have an actually quite nice implementation of this with express and mongoose: http://nmajor.com/posts/multi-tenancy-with-expressmongoose

I hope this is of any help for you, and if you manage to find a solution or something, where you can show some simple code, please post it as there seems to be a lot of people asking about this.

Cheers.